# keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ to switch between tabs within a single project without navigating to a different project

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm currently using IntelliJ IDEA version 2023.3 RC. When I have several projects open, they're displayed as tabs rather than separate windows. Yet, the trouble arises when I try to switch tabs for files—it ends up switching to a different project, which is really annoying.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEq10.png)

I tried clicking in the menu without shortcut and it works as expected: Window => Editor Tabs => Select Next Tab.
I suspected there might be key bindings conflict so I double checked there are no conflicts with MacOS.

Update: I managed to solve this problem by modifying the shortcut within the IDE. What I discovered was that the shortcut I initially configured in the IDE (`Shift+Cmd+]`) coincided with a MacOS system shortcut. Consequently, whenever I invoked this shortcut, it triggered a double action: the system used it to toggle between project tabs, while the IDE used it to switch between editor tabs.